# Django Foreign Key model cant display in view JSON

Tags: django, python-3.x

When I run this, I get JSON file but the foreign key (contact numbers) are not included, I want to display one contact name/address/email with multiple contact numbers.

models.py

```
 from django.db import models

class PhoneBook(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='address')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='email')
    note = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='note')
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.name



class ContactNumber(models.Model):  
    number = models.ForeignKey(PhoneBook, related_name="contact_numbers")
    contact_number= models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.contact_number
```

views.py

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import PhoneBook,ContactNumber
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View

class PhoneBookList(View):
    def get(self,request):
        phonebooklist=list(PhoneBook.objects.values())
        return JsonResponse(phonebooklist,safe=False)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import PhoneBook,ContactNumber

class ContactNumberInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ContactNumber

class PhoneBookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines =[
        ContactNumberInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(PhoneBook)
admin.site.register(ContactNumber)
```

RESULT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWiPl.png)

Comment: Is your application architecture based only on API?

Comment: You are only querying `PhoneBook` instances. Django admin has nothing to do with your views.

Comment: @Shift'NTab yes, based only on API. I am making this as backend and frontend reactjs

Comment: @Selcuk I got only problem on my views.py? How about on my models.py? should I create some function their to be able to display the foreign key (contact numbers) together with the contact names?

Comment: I strongly advice to have a look at django restframework, it make things easier,

Comment: @Shift'NTab we have required not to use django restframework, that's the problem :(

Comment: dunno why, but thats a bad decision..

Comment: [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWiPl.png this is the result

Comment: @Shift'NTab Because this looks like a school assignment.

Comment: @Selcuk never thought about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be able to answer with this approach.

```
class PhoneBook(models.Model):
    ....

    def to_json(self):

        contact_numbers = [c.contact_number 
                     for c in self.contact_numbers.all()]

        return { 
            'name':            self.name, 
            'email':           self.email, 
            'address':         self.address,
            'note':            self.note,
            'contact_numbers': contact_numbers
        }
```

In your view.

```
class PhoneBookList(View):
    def get(self,request):
        phonebooklist = PhoneBook.objects.all()
        serialized_data = [pb.to_json() for pb in phonebooklist]
        return JsonResponse(serialized_data, safe=False)
```

A bit dirty solution though

Comment: it's working now but it is saying that 
**'dict' object has no attribute 'contact_numbers'**
http://prntscr.com/jodpc8

Comment: if am removing the <code>.values()</code>
I am getting error in the name or other fields.
http://prntscr.com/jodu47

Comment: I still can't figure out the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer it should work by now, just enclose the properties with a single quote.

Comment: dapat, gamit ka ng restframework  *(your must, use restframework)*

Comment: our company said that, we should not use restframework because they are not using restframework on their current project, so we are told that we should not also use rest framework because their existing project that is still ongoing is don't have restframework. I really have hardtime doing this, thank you so much.

Comment: I already have knowledge on using restframework, but they don't want to use it. Now, I am having hard time on how to do it, I can't find any tutorial over the internet on making own api.

Comment: django has a lot of stuffs how you can serialized data without using restframework, the company are just afraid of the changes, in fact they don't have the time to study some tech to improve.

Comment: exactly, most of the tutorial over the internet are using restframework. That's why I am having hard time making it manually, I can't figure out on now on POST together with the foreign key .

Comment: dont be afraid to post more here on SO lots of expert can help you

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll do that. That's why I created my stackoverflow account because I can't find any solution on my problem for doing manually.

Comment: Do you have any idea if now I want to display only one contact name with multiple contact numbers? I can display the list of numbers for one particular contact name, but I can't combine them together like what you did. Any idea?

Comment: @ajiejot post new question